# Replacing double quotes in filename using Python?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase

I am working with data in an SDE, when I create a new feature class within the SDE I get a file name which contains my user name in double quotes. I do not have administrative permissions to the SDE and therefore cannot get the file name to write without having my user name in double quotes. I was wondering if there is a way to replace the double quotation marks in the file name so I can write an output to a shapefile. When I try to output to a shapefile I get an error stating 'invalid characters'. I've tried .replace('"','') but that doesn't seem to work. The only replace function I can get to work is replacing full stops in the file name by stating .replace(".","") using double quotes.

How do I replace these troublesome double quotes?

Comment: `.replace('"', "")`

Comment: Does your RDBMS user name have space in it? Table names and file names are very different things.  A sample of your code with log output might demonstrate the issue more clearly.

Comment: Thanks @Paul that seemed to do the trick. Also, just to clarify my user name did not have a space in it.  My code is as follows:buffRep = 'bufferfc.replace(".","").replace('"',"").replace("UserName","")' from there I run Clip and the shapefile file name outputs as I want it to.